# Eclipse RCP: Error when exporting Sample Eclipse Product

Tags: java, eclipse-pde

I've set up jdk-15.0.2+7 from AdoptOpenJDK.
I've set up Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers (version: 2020-12 (4.18.0), Build id: 20201210-1552).
I started Eclipse, created Plug-in Project PortfolioAnalyzer with default settings:

- Target platform: Eclipse,
- Create a rich client application? Yes
- Plug-in Template: Eclipse 4 RCP Application
- Checkbox Create sample content (part, menu, command...): True

Then I

- open PortfolioAnalyzer.product with default Product Configuration Editor, tab Overview and click link Eclipse Product export wizard in Exporting section
- specify Destination directory: D:\rcp_out, all settings by default.

And get error:

```
D:\Work\Eclipse\Java\PortfolioAnalyzer\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:477: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Vadim\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.900.v20201111-1557\scripts\genericTargets.xml:240: A problem occured while invoking the director.
The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Work\Eclipse\Java\PortfolioAnalyzer\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:477: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Vadim\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.900.v20201111-1557\scripts\genericTargets.xml:240: A problem occured while invoking the director.
```

I've edited

```
C:\Users\Vadim\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.900.v20201111-1557\scripts\genericTargets.xml
```

by adding in target `runDirector` the following line just after properties definitions:

```
<record name="d:/build.log" loglevel="verbose" append="false"/>
```

In the case I get the log file when the error occurs. This is its content:

```
Property "p2.director.log" has not been set
[p2.director] Installing App 1.0.0.202102120000.
[p2.director] Installation failed.
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director]   Software being installed: PortfolioAnalyzer 1.0.0.202102120000 (App 1.0.0.202102120000)
[p2.director]   Missing requirement: PortfolioAnalyzer 1.0.0.202102120000 (PortfolioAnalyzer 1.0.0.202102120000) requires 'osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=15))' but it could not be found
[p2.director]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
[p2.director]       From: PortfolioAnalyzer 1.0.0.202102120000 (App 1.0.0.202102120000)
[p2.director]       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; PortfolioAnalyzer [1.0.0.202102120000,1.0.0.202102120000]
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director] Software being installed: PortfolioAnalyzer 1.0.0.202102120000 (App 1.0.0.202102120000)
[p2.director] Missing requirement: PortfolioAnalyzer 1.0.0.202102120000 (PortfolioAnalyzer 1.0.0.202102120000) requires 'osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=15))' but it could not be found
[p2.director] Cannot satisfy dependency:
A problem occured while invoking the director.
runDirector:  duration 0 seconds
```

Could you explain how to fix the problem? Should `p2.director.log` property be set somehow? Or something wrong with `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu`?

Comment: The Export RCP code is deprecated and no longer works well. [tag:tycho] and [tag:maven] is the only supported way to build a RCP. For example see [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, I'll look at the article. At first sight my simple task doesn't seem so simple )